Pasar un Webscraping a un DataFrame
he realizado el web scraping de una web (no es una tabla, son datos sueltos) y estoy intentando poner los resultados en forma de tabla, entiendo que se hace importando panda. Se crear un DataFrame con sus columnas a partir de un diccionario pero con este webscraping no hay manera.
Muchísimas gracias por vuestro tiempo.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re



def datos_ICAB(url):
    d = {}           #diccionario de salida
    headers = {
        "user-agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/126.0.0.0"
        }       #Encabezado de la petició HTTP
    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=10)     #para que le de un tiempo prudencial para realizar el request al servidor.
    if req.status_code != 200:
        return {"Error" : f"{req.reason}", "status_code" : f"{req.status_code}"}
    d["url"] = req.url
    d["id"] = d["url"].split("=")[-1]   #nr de colegiat
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
    d["Nom advocat"] = soup.find("h1", class_="title").text.strip() #Nombre del abogado.
    d["E-mail"] = soup.find("li", class_="email").text.strip() #E-mail.
    d["Publicitat"] = soup.find("span", class_="note-error").text.strip() #si quiere o no publicitat.
    return d



url = 'https://www.icab.es/ca/colegi/membres/index.html?id='  #la url no es completa, a la derecha de todo de la url, vendrá el nr de colegiado.
i = 1
f = 10


for i in range(f):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        try:
            datos = datos_ICAB(url + str(i))
        except AttributeError:
            continue
    try:
        for clave, valor in datos.items():
            print(f'{clave.upper}: {valor}')
    except NameError:
            continue
    print()     #Salto de linea.

